# TextView con varios estilos

Tags: android

Es posible crear un único TextView y situar en el varios textos con diferentes estilos?
[image: Resultado esperado]
Resultado esperado

De no ser posible hacerlo con un único TV, como sería la mejor forma?
Un saludo

Comment: Nuevamente te invitamos a leer [ask] y agregar en tus preguntas lo que has tratado o investigado, revisa [ask] por favor, saludos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si, es posible utilizando la clase [SpannableString](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/SpannableString) o SpannableStringBuilder si queremos que la cadena sea mutable.

```kotlin
val textView : TextView = findViewById(R.id.textview)
val spannableText = SpannableString("Texto a cambiar dentro del span")

spannableText.span= TextAppearanceSpan(context, R.style.myStyle), 0, 5, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE)
spannableText.setSpan(TextAppearanceSpan(context, R.style.myNextStyle), 6, 10, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE)

textView.text = spannableText
```

Comment: Gracias por tu  contribución, ayúdanos a responder preguntas que hayan sido creadas en base a [ask], saludos.